# How can I apply a function on each date in an Interval[DateObject[],DateObject[]] in Wolfram-Language?

Tags: wolfram-language

Line 2 of the following code:

```
dates = Interval[DateObject[{2019, 7, 5}],DateObject[{2019, 7, 7}]]
Map[Function[d,DateValue[d,"DayNameShort"]],dates]
```

yields:

```
Interval[Fri,Sun]
```

... but I want to give:

```
{Fri,Sat,Sun}
```

... how can I 'peel off' each day (not millisecond!) which falls within the interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateRange[d1,d2]` instead of `Interval[d1,d2]`!

Comment: Nice! Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.